# Where can I find an exhaustive list of Ryūkyūan personal names?

Tags: names, culture, ryukyuan-languages

According to Wikipedia, "Okinawan name", speaking about the *warabi-naa* 童名, the primary personal names of Ryūkyū:

> A set of *warabi-naa* appeared in the very beginning of recorded history and has not been changed since then. The number of warabi-naa pooled in society was extremely small. It was not uncommon for a warabi-naa to be shared by more than one person in a household.

So, the set is small and defined. Where can I find that set? The Japanese version of the article provides examples of *warabi-naa*, without attempt at exhausting.

Comment: Sounds like a resource question. For the city of Naha, the following should help (I have no idea how they differ across islands)  https://note.com/sumuchiyuma/n/n8c44ee5a3532